# A series expansion formula for the residues of a function having an infinite number of poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, meromorphic-functions

**Question** : Let $f(z)$ be such that along the path $C_N$ ([illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2qz3.png)), $|f(z)| \leq M/{|z|^k}$, where $k > 1$, and $M$ are constants independent of $N$.

Show that 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \big\{ \textrm{sum of the residues of} ~ \pi \cot (\pi z) f(z) ~ \textrm{at the poles of} ~f(z) \big\}.$$

I was able to prove it when $f(z)$ has a finite number of poles, using the Residue theorem.

How can I go by and prove the result when $f(z)$ has an infinite number of poles ? My feeling is this is an application of **Mittag-Leffler theorem**. But I couldn't really work it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For $f$ meromorphic on the whole complex plane and satisfying your bound then $$0=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{C_N} f(z)\pi \cot(\pi z)dz=\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{a\in Int(C_N)} Res(f(z)\pi \cot(\pi z),a)$$

If $f$ has no poles on $\Bbb{Z}$ **and** $\sum_n f(n)$ converges then you get your result, where the sum over the poles of $f$ is in the $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{a\in Int(C_N)}  $ sense, in general you can't change the order of summation.